# How to map complex one-to-many with Entity Framework and Fluent API

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, fluent-interface

I'm coming from Java and is now implementing an existing system into a database with C# and Entity Framework.

Since I cannot show the actual classes here, I've tried to make an example identical to my problem, which is as follows.
I have a `Company` which has several property lists to `Person`. When I'm using EF to convert this into the database, I'm getting a new foreign key column for each instance of `Person`.

```
Company
   public GUID CompanyID {get,set}
   public List<Person> Employee{get,set}
   public List<Person> Janitors {get,set}
   public List<Person> Students {get,set}
   public List<Person> Professors {get,set}    

Person
   public GUID CompanyID {get,set}
```

I would like the database scheme of Person to be

```
|Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Company_FK |
----------------------------------------------
```

But now it is more like this

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Company_ID  | Company_ID1 | Company_ID2 ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                     null          reference      null
                                     null          reference      null
                                    reference         null        null
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~etc~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

All those Company_ID* columns have references to the same Company table, therefor I believe that it is not impossible to just have one column for this reference, and then loose all those `null` references.

I need a solution with Fluent API, not Data Annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with your company configuration:

```
HasMany(x => x.Employee).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyID);
HasMany(x => x.Janitors).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyID);
HasMany(x => x.Students).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyID);
HasMany(x => x.Professors).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyID);
```

Comment: It was successful, but I got this error message "The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship." But your code worked, and I'm grateful for your help @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow